# Can't find Windows 10 emulator in VS2015 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2015, emulation, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I've installed VS2015 Professional on windows 10, I want to install the windows 10 mobile emulators but I receive an error on install, for UWP development. I've tried the standalone SDK but it states it's up to date. Iv'e also tried the modify VS2015 install and I can only see windows 10 SDK kit installed and windows 8.1 emulators.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Emulator is based on Hyper-V and Hyper-V is only part of Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise. If you use the Home Edition, you can't install the emulator. Here you have to buy a Win10 Pro license and upgrade the edition to Pro.